# What are the recommended GNU linker options to specify $ORIGIN in RPATH?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared, rpath

Assume my platform is vanilla (non-embedded) x86-64 Linux using GNU build toolchain (GCC, etc.).

To specify `$ORIGIN` in `RPATH`, I know about the linker option: `-Wl,-rpath,'\$\$ORIGIN'`.

Today, I discovered another option: `-Wl,-z,origin`.

Should I **always** include `-Wl,-z,origin` when using `-Wl,-rpath,'\$\$ORIGIN'`?

[Official GNU ld docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/Options.html), say:

> Marks the object may contain $ORIGIN.

Related, but different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853271/what-are-the-recommended-gnu-linker-options-to-specify-rpath

Comment: One common trick to avoid having the shell mangle this flag is to set `ORIGIN='$ORIGIN'`. Of course it still has to be protected from make and whatever makefile-generator you are using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I know about the linker option: `-Wl,-rpath,'\$\$ORIGIN'`

You know wrong: above option will *not* do what you want. The option you want is `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'`. The difference:

```
echo "int main() { }" | gcc -xc - -Wl,-rpath,'\$\$ORIGIN' &&
readelf -d a.out | grep ORIGIN

 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [\$\$ORIGIN]

echo "int main() { }" | gcc -xc - -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' &&
readelf -d a.out | grep ORIGIN

 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN]
```

> Should I always include `-Wl,-z,origin`

The `-Wl,-z,origin` sets `DF_ORIGIN` in `FLAGS_1` dynamic entry.

As of current GLIBC trunk, *nothing* looks at the value of that flag, so if you target `GLIBC` (most Linux programs do), the answer is: it doesn't matter one bit whether you use `-z origin` or not.

The answer may be different for other libc implementations. However, Solaris libc (where the whole `$ORIGIN` is coming from) also does not appear to require the `DF_ORIGIN` to be set, so it's probably a safe bet to ignore this completely.

Comment: *Outstanding.*  Thank you for correcting my (mis)understanding about quoting `$ORIGIN` correctly.  Also, I didn't know about the `gcc -` trick to compile a trivial programs on the command line.

Comment: Do you also know the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853271/what-are-the-recommended-gnu-linker-options-to-specify-rpath?

Comment: It seems at least some older BSD derivatives (e.g. DragonFly v5.6.2) will ignore to resolve `$ORIGIN` if the option `-z origin` is not present when linking. Unfortunately some linkers as e.g. from mingw will error with `unrecognized option '-z'`.